# Printer Works Fine, Refuses to Show Up in Devices and Printers

Tags: windows-10, printing, network-printer

I've been having this problem for months, and for a while I was ignoring it.

It all started when I wanted to share my HP Deskjet 1050, connected to my desktop via usb, over my network to use on laptops, etc. I followed the usual procedure of going to devices and printers and preparing to share it, but to my surprise it wasn't listed there. Now, this was a shock, because I had been printing fine on it for months. It shows up in every print dialog, and shows as working in device manager as well. However, even when I attempt to "add a new printer" it refuses to be recognized.

Currently running Win10 Pro. I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, restarting, and cleaning up and nothing has solved the problem thus far.

I'm just very confused. All I want is to be able to print wirelessly from my laptop. Somehow this printer is hiding from the Devices and Printers menu. Even more frustratingly, when I go to settings in Device Manager it tells me I need to go to Devices and Printers to change settings.

Aren't printers wonderful? It's amazing how consistently they seem to misbehave and refuse to work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen so far it looks like a corruption in one of your installed printers. Either in the driver or in the port. I have fixed this a couple of times by removing ALL printers and rebooting causing windows to reinstall all of the printers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/18382-devices-printers-icons-missing-following-update-windows-10-a.html

The bottom line is that the "Device" services have been disabled.  All of them should be set to `Manual`.

If you start them, then you don't need a reboot for the devices to show. Otherwise, a reboot will start the services as needed and show all the printers in `Devices and Printers`.

Answer (score 0):

Symptoms in Windows 10: Add shared printer wizard is completed succesfuuly but the printer is not showing up in the Printers And Scanner window.

CAUSE: The printer is already added into **DEVICE MANAGER/Printer queue

FIX: Add temporary Administrator rigths to the affected user. Goto Control Panel/Printer Queue and remote the shared printer. Remove administrator rigts for the affected user an logon again. Add shared printer normaly.